# We recommend that he provide/provides?

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood, conjugation

To my ear "We recommend that he provide an appropriate response" sounds better than "provides"

what is this tense/construct called and which is right ?

Comment: Are you a native English speaker? I am an ESL learner and I thought this is only confusing for foreigners like me a lot, but is this grammatical matter so subtle as to be confusing for native English speakers as well?

Answer (score 3):

That's the subjunctive mood.
http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/verbs/29/subjunctive-mood/

We do not need to add a(n) *s*.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.......the **s** is not required ..........this is similar to:

*He should provide an appropriate response.*

vs

*He provides an appropriate response.*

Answer (score -1):

OH, "We recommend that he provide an appropriate response" without 's' is the correct answer, I used to do the English test which has the similar question... I chose 'provides' --> I was wrong!!!